# In Python, how do I obtain the current frame?

Tags: python

In other languages I can obtain the current frame via a reflection api to determine what variables are local to the scope that I an currently in.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: The first Google result for "python inspect stack frame" returns the answer you want; http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Comment: note that u can use locals() to obtain local vars

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
import sys    
sys._getframe(number)
```

The number being 0 for the current frame and 1 for the frame up and so on up.

The best introduction I have found to frames in python is [here](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/framehack/index.html)

However, look at the inspect module as it does most common things you want to do with frames.

Answer (score 43):

The best answer would be to use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) module; not a private function in `sys`.

```
import inspect

current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
```

Comment: Thanks. But one thing to note, from that link: "CPython implementation detail: This function relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python. If running in an implementation without Python stack frame support this function returns None."

Comment: The `inspect.currentframe()` implementation actually calls the "private method in `sys`": `sys._getframe(1) if hasattr(sys, "_getframe") else None`.

See [line 1536](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py#L1536) on the cpython codebase. This also means that even calling `sys` might not do the trick.

Answer (score 26):

I use these little guys for debugging and logging:

```
import os
import sys

def LINE( back = 0 ):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_lineno
def FILE( back = 0 ):
   return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_code.co_filename
def FUNC( back = 0):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_code.co_name
def WHERE( back = 0 ):
   frame = sys._getframe( back + 1 )
   return "%s/%s %s()" % ( os.path.basename( frame.f_code.co_filename ), 
                           frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_name )
```

Comment: Is it possible to obtains frame's full path ?

Comment: This might have been nice back in 2009, but users should just use stdlib [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) these days.