# Capture file and line number for an exception that wasn't raised

Tags: python, exception

Is it possible to collect the file and line number where an exception object was created if that object is never raised?

Example:

```
def compute_score_for_test(test):
  # Exceptions can be added to a test explicitly.
  if test_is_unscorable(test):
    test.add_error(UnscorableTestError('...'))

  ...

  # During certain operations, caught exceptions also get added to a test.
  try:
    ...
  except Exception as e:
    test.add_error(e)

... much later ...

for test in test_set:
  for error in test.errors:
    # Using print as a contrived example; we actually store these values in a database.
    print '[%s] %s (%s:%d)' % (
      error.__class__.__name__,
      error.message,
      error.file_name,    # <- ...somehow
      error.line_number,  #
    )
```

Adding code to `test.add_error()` is an option if there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a simplified version of] the solution we ultimately went with.  It handles caught exceptions as well as passing exception objects directly to `add_error()`.

```
from inspect import getsourcefile, getfile, getlineno, stack
from sys import exc_info

...

def add_error(self, error):
    """
    Adds an error to the test.

    :type error: Exception
    """
    error.file = None
    error.line = None

    # Try to guess the file and line number where the error occurred.
    exc_tb = exc_info()[2]

    try:
        if exc_tb:
            # If we have traceback info (i.e., from a caught exception), add it to the error.
            error.file = (getsourcefile(exc_tb.tb_frame) or getfile(exc_tb.tb_frame))
            error.line = getlineno(exc_tb.tb_frame)
        else:
            #
            # Otherwise, find the caller in the current stack.
            #
            # stack()[1] = (<frame object>, filename, line_number, caller, context_line, pos_in_context_line)
            # Note that we pass 0 to `stack()` so that it doesn't return any context lines,
            #  since we're not interested in that.
            #
            (error.file, error.line) = stack(0)[1][1:3]
    except Exception as e:
        # Well, we tried.
        error.file = '(unable to determine due to %s %r)' % (e.__class__.__name__, e.message,)
    finally:
        #
        # Very important to make sure `exc_tb` gets deleted to prevent a circular reference.  Although Python's GC
        #   is smart enough to catch this and free the memory anyway, it's better not to create the circular
        #   reference in the first place.
        #
        # :see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info
        #
        del exc_tb

    self.errors.append(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current line with the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module, like so:

```
import inspect

def lineno():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

def filename():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename
```

You can just store that information in your Error object (which by the way, need not be an `Exception` and could very well be any other meaningful type given that you don't ever `raise` it).

In case you are curious about the `lineno()` function, `inspect.currentframe()` gives the current frame, `f_back` gives the parent one (that is, the line at which the function gets called) and `f_lineno` gives obviously the line number.

The `filename()` function operates in a similar manner. Take a look at the `inspect` module documentation to see all the things you can get from the current frame. It's actually pretty complete.

In your case, I would go for something like:

```
test.add_error(YourError(frame_info=get_frame_info())
```

And:

```
import inspect

def get_frame_info():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back

    return frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_filename
```

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140513/866915) shows how to get the current file and line number, e.g.:

```
import sys

def LINE( back = 0 ):
    return sys._getframe( back + 1 ).f_lineno
def FILE( back = 0 ):

def foo():
  print "this is line number", LINE(), " of file ", FILE()
```

and you can put that information into your error object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the Python logging module (which is made for this kind of stuff), and use its formatting options. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

An example:

```
import logging
message_format = '[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(pathname)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s]\n%(message)s\n'
logging.basicConfig(format=message_format)
logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.error('Testing 1, 2, 3...')
```